# Find the length of a side length in terms of w to minimize the triangle area

Tags: calculus

A sheet of paper has width $w,$ so $AB = w$ in the diagram below. The bottom right corner is folded over crease $\overline{PQ},$ so that $B$ goes to $B'$ on the left edge of the paper. Find the length of $BP,$ in terms of $w,$ such that the area of triangle $B'PQ$ is minimized.[image]

You can assume that the sheet of paper extends vertically indefinitely.

So far, I've found that the triangle's area in terms of PQ is $\frac{PQ^2 \sin \theta \cos \theta}{2}$. However, I'm having trouble finishing off by representing side lengths in terms of w.

Comment: Which angle is your $\theta$?

Comment: $\theta$ is angle BQP. So sorry for not mentioning this earlier!

Comment: Assuming Q is fixed,  the closer $P$ is to $B$ the smaller the area,,  so you need to figure out how small you can make $PB$ and still have the fold reach point $B'$ on the other side

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Let
\begin{align} 
|AP|&=w(1-t)
,\quad
|BP|=|B'P|=wt
,\quad t\in(\tfrac12,1)
.
\end{align}

Then
\begin{align} 
|AB'|&=\sqrt{|B'P|^2-|AP|^2}
=w\sqrt{2t-1}
,\\
\cos2\angle QPB
&=\cos(\pi-\angle APB')
=-\cos(\angle APB')=-\frac{|AP|}{|B'P|}
,\\
\cos\angle QPB
&=\sqrt{1-\frac1{2t}}
,\\
|PQ|&=\frac{|BP|}{\cos\angle QPB}
=
\frac{w\,t^{3/2}\sqrt2}{\sqrt{2t-1}}
.
\end{align}

And the area in question in terms of $w$ and $t$ is found as

\begin{align} 
[B'PQ]=[BPQ]=
S_w(t)&=
\tfrac12\,wt\sqrt{\left(\frac{w\,t^{3/2}\sqrt2}{\sqrt{2t-1}}\right)^2-w^2t^2}
\\
&=
\frac{w^2 t^2}{2\sqrt{2t-1}}
.
\end{align}

Now by differentiating $S_w$ with respect to $t$ we can find that

\begin{align} 
\min_{t\in(\tfrac12,1)} S_w(t)
=S_w(\tfrac23)
=\tfrac29\sqrt3\,w^2
.
\end{align}

Comment: Why does  $BP=B'P$?

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg: Well, the OP states that "The bottom right corner is folded over crease $\overline{PQ}$, so that $B$ goes to $B′$ on the left edge of the paper."